# definition of implicit copy assignment operator for 'time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration

Tags: boost, boost-asio

boost version 1.72.0

**Question**> What should I do to fix this build issues?

```
boost_1.72.0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:16:
boost_1.72.0/boost/date_time/time_duration.hpp:68:5: error: definition of implicit copy assignment operator for 'time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits<boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits_adapted64_impl, boost::date_time::micro, 1000000, 6>>' is deprecated because it has a user-declared copy constructor [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-copy]
    time_duration(const time_duration<T, rep_type>& other)
    ^
boost_1.72.0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:57:30: note: in implicit copy assignment operator for 'boost::date_time::time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits<boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits_adapted64_impl, boost::date_time::micro, 1000000, 6>>' first required here
  class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE time_duration :
                             ^
boost_1.72.0/boost/date_time/time_duration.hpp:286:30: note: in implicit move assignment operator for 'boost::posix_time::time_duration' first required here
  class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE subsecond_duration : public base_duration
                             ^
note: in implicit move assignment operator for 'boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000>' first 

required here
delay_int = boost::posix_time::microseconds(microSeconds);
          ^

class ABC
{
...
  void set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds);
  boost::posix_time::microseconds delay_int{0};
...
};

void ABC::set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds)
{
  delay_int = boost::posix_time::microseconds(microSeconds); // this line doesn't pass compiler checking
}
```

Update-1: based on the suggestion, I switch to use time_duration and the issue still persists.

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:
In file included from boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:15:
In file included from boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12:
In file included from boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13:
In file included from boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:16:
boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/time_duration.hpp:68:5: error: definition of implicit copy assignment operator for 'time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits<boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits_adapted64_impl, boost::date_time::micro, 1000000, 6>>' is deprecated because it has a user-declared copy constructor [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-copy]
    time_duration(const time_duration<T, rep_type>& other)
    ^
boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:57:30: note: in implicit copy assignment operator for 'boost::date_time::time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits<boost::date_time::time_resolution_traits_adapted64_impl, boost::date_time::micro, 1000000, 6>>' first required here
  class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE time_duration :
                             ^
main.cpp:17:15: note: in implicit move assignment operator for 'boost::posix_time::time_duration' first required here
    delay_int = boost::posix_time::microseconds(
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_CONCEPTS
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsuggest-override"

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class ABC {
   public:
    void set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds);

   private:
    boost::posix_time::time_duration delay_int;
};

void ABC::set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds) {
    delay_int = boost::posix_time::microseconds(
        microSeconds);  // this line doesn't pass compiler checking
}

int main() {
    ABC abc;
    abc.set_delay(123123);

    std::cout << sizeof(boost::posix_time::microseconds) << " bytes\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(boost::posix_time::time_duration) << " bytes\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the warning, even with Boost 1.72.0, older GCC/Clang and the flags `-Wall -Werror -Wdeprecated-copy -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion`, see [Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Mx5rsf3j3).

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class ABC {
  public:
    void set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds);

  private:
    boost::posix_time::microseconds delay_int{0};
};

void ABC::set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds) {
    delay_int =
        boost::posix_time::microseconds(microSeconds); // this line doesn't pass compiler checking
}

int main() {
    ABC abc;
    abc.set_delay(123123);
}
```

In general it *is* just a warning. Also, it seems to be caused by the fact that the subsecond divisions aren't really designed for direct use (but rather to aid initialization of `time_duration<>` instances).

I wager the problem goes away if you use that instead:

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration delay_int;
```

Note also that both types have the same footprint, just `time_duration` has the application-level interface that you'd expect.

**[Live As Well](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/1fKerPxre)**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class ABC {
   public:
    void set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds);

   private:
    boost::posix_time::time_duration delay_int;
};

void ABC::set_delay(uint32_t microSeconds) {
    delay_int = boost::posix_time::microseconds(
        microSeconds);  // this line doesn't pass compiler checking
}

int main() {
    ABC abc;
    abc.set_delay(123123);

    std::cout << sizeof(boost::posix_time::microseconds) << " bytes\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(boost::posix_time::time_duration) << " bytes\n";
}
```

Prints

```
8 bytes
8 bytes
```

Comment: I tried to use the `time_duration` instead of `microsends` for the type of the variable but the issues still exist. So far, I only have seen this compiler errors through Intel(R) oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler 2021.3.0 (2021.3.0.20210619). However, I am not able to reproduce the same problems through the online compiler. Thank you!

Comment: It would have been helpful to specify that - since it is not exactly a mainstream compiler. Anyhow, that seems to be the explanation then